# Distinct σ-Algebras of a Set with infinite number of elements

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Is it possible to construct 2 distinct σ-Algebras of a Set (e.g. Integers) with neither of them having finite number of elements?

Comment: Maybe i didnt understand. On $\mathbb{R}$ take the borelians and the "discrete" $\sigma$-algebra, i.e. $\{M:M\subseteq\mathbb{R}\}$.

Comment: @Basti I meant that each of the σ-Algebras having non-finite elements. One being the Power Set is evident. I was looking for another one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. For any $k$, let $B_k$ be the collection of subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ that either contain *every* multiple of $k$ or *none* of them. Then $B_k$ is a $\sigma$-algebra for every $k$, and no two of them are the same. In fact, $B_2$ and $B_3$ aren't even contained in one another.

In the comments, Basti gave a good example of a pair of distinct $\sigma$-algebras on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I am not sure I understood what you meant. B{2}= [{}, {2}, {2,4}, {2,4,6}, ...., {1}, {1,3}, {1,3,5}.....]. But, the complement of {2}, {1,3,4,5} doesn't belong to B{2}.

Comment: No, $\{2\}$ is not in $B_2$, because (a) not *every* even number is in $\{2\}$, but (b) *some* even numbers are. Sets in $B_2$ include $\{0,2,4,6,8,\ldots\}$ (because it contains *every* even number) and $\{1,3,5\}$ (because it contains *none* of them).

Comment: Got it. Thanks!